# Expo Router - Back button disappears when switching between tabs in tab navigator

Tags: expo-router

I would like to illustrate a problem I have encountered nesting stack navigators inside tab navigators with expo router.

[image]

The above is what I believe to be a very common app layout.  It is a stack navigator that contains some children (in this case, a modal and a tab navigator).  The tab navigator in turn contains two other stack navigators, in this example "Cupboards" and "Shelves".

When I navigate into the actual cupboards and shelves screens, I very soon cannot obtain a back button and get stuck at the deepest level of the stacks.  See video below.  I am fairly certain I have followed all the correct setup protocol.  My code is [here](https://gitlab.com/andreweinhorn/nested-navigators).  I used the suggested setup of `npx create-expo-app@latest --template tabs@49` and modified it to created the above.

https://github.com/expo/router/assets/2414383/498aa233-ce57-4267-841e-9fee25e5a6ff

Is this the expected behaviour of expo router?  I think this one reason why people are asking for a reset function (see discussion [here](https://github.com/expo/router/discussions/495)).  I am considering moving back to react navigation, but am praying I am wrong about something here as I really like file-based navigation.